# How do I stop Subdivision surface modifier from applying 'too much'?

Tags: subdivision-surface

When I was earlier using Blender tutorials, Subsurf modifier seemed quite 'gentle'. Now, as I'm trying to model a 2D car door, it seems like it's subdividing everything far too much. My end game is simply a slightly curvier version of the car door in the image. I've tried insetting the car window, adding loop cuts, but then turning it into Subsurf modifier makes it look like a cartoon handbag.

[image: How it looks without subdivision surface modifier]

[image: how it looks WITH subdivision surface modifier]

Please help!

Comment: Yes thanks! Key takeaway for me is: "Make sure to subdivide the mesh AT LEAST TWICE before using a subdivide modifier as there isn't enough polygons for it to look right"

Comment: You actually don't need that many polygons, in your case you just need to add some support edges